# Why is ng-repeat being commented in devtools?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

When I try to populate the options, nothing shows. In devtools, the ng-repeat seems to be commented out.  See here:

[image]

The option tag is not being recognised. I have tested my api's and they are working. Here is my HTML:

```
     <body ng-controller="CarController as carCtrl">
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li>Welcome ....</li>
                <li><a href="index.html">Log Out</href></a></li>
                <li><a href="ownerHome.html">Home</href></a></li>

            </ul>
        </nav>
        
            <div class="innerContainer">

      <label> Search
   <input type="text" list="dataList">
      </label>
             <datalist id="dataList">
        <option ng-repeat="type in carCtrl.types" value="{{type}}"> Type {{type}}</option>
      </datalist>

            </div>

        <footer>
            <a href="#" class="fa fa-facebook"></a>
            <a href="#" class="fa fa-instagram"></a>
            <a href="#" class="fa fa-envelope"></a>

        </footer>

    </body>
```

Here is my angularjs:

```
module.controller('CarController', function (registerCarAPI, $window, $sessionStorage, carAPI, carOwnerAPI, carTypeAPI, $scope) {
    this.listMessage = "Please register your car here:";
    this.types = carTypeAPI.query();
    this.cars = carAPI.query();


    this.ownerCars = carOwnerAPI.query({'ownerId': $sessionStorage.owner.OwnerID});


    this.registerCar = function (car) {


        car.ownerId = $sessionStorage.owner.OwnerID;
        registerCarAPI.save(null, car,
                function () {
                    $window.location = 'viewCars.html';
                },
                function (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                }

        );
    };


});
```

Comment: Can you share your rendered output? Just the datalist element, surrounding angular comments, and its contents should be sufficient.

Comment: I have added a photo at the start of the post. Is this enough?

Comment: The only reason angular would do that is if carCtrl.types was empty or non existent. Are you sure it's a valid set of data? IF so, can you post what it looks like?

Answer (score 0):

You're using it like a select object which might be causing the issue. Try changing your `datalist` html to be like this:

```
<datalist id="dataList">
  <option ng-repeat="type in carCtrl.types" value="{{type}}"> 
</datalist>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately this isn't the issue.